# Toggle button in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How to make a toggle button in MFC dialog,?
Like the one you usually used in switching on the wifi in smart phone, push like switch button and radion buttons are not my needs,

Uptil now i reached to changing the switch button to push like effect but i need the real toggle button effect as describe about those in smartphones.

Remember that it supports dragging to on from off and vice versa.... :(

Comment: Try using the `BS_PUSHLIKE` style on a check-box: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/21/5021765.aspx

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? TRACKMOUSEEVENT is one good option to detect when mouse has left the button and appropriately paint the button.

Comment: Can't you simulate that kind of buttons using a Slider?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/794577/Windows-Forms-ToggleButton

Answer (score 3):

You can keep 2 images that are visible when button is pressed and one when button is not pressed. Now you can use [CBitmapButton::LoadBitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6acs49.aspx) or [CButton::SetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1446sbt.aspx) to change the image everytime the button is clicked. Make sure to invalidate the button so that new image can take effect.

```
//load your bitmaps (in constructor if dialog)
m_wifionBitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_WIFION);
m_wifioffBitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_WIFIOFF);

// In turn_on_wifi()
CButton* pButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_WIFI_TOGGLE_BUTTON);
pButton->SetBitmap(HBITMAP)m_wifionBitmap);

// In turn_off_wifi()
CButton* pButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_WIFI_TOGGLE_BUTTON);
pButton->SetBitmap(HBITMAP)m_wifioffBitmap);
```

Comment: thanx, i think that will work for me, but can you help me in dragging support there, i will accept your answer if i didn't find that and used this approach